# How can I fix this for loop to solve a system of linear equations through the Jacobi iteration method?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, numerical-methods

I'm trying to write a function that goes through the Jacobi iteration method for solving a system of linear equations. I've got most of it down, I just need to figure out how to iterate the last for loop either 1000 times or until the break condition is met. How can I make it so the value of x updates each iteration?

```
import numpy as np

def Jacobi(A,b,err):
    n = A.shape
    k = np.zeros(n[0])
    D = np.zeros(n)
    U = np.zeros(n)
    L = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n[0]):
        for j in range(n[0]):
            if i == j:
                D[i,j] = A[i,j]
            elif i < j:
                U[i,j] = A[i,j]
            else:
                L[i,j] = A[i,j]
    w = []
    for i in range(1000):
        x = np.linalg.inv(D)*(U+L)*x +np.linalg.inv(D)*b
        w.append(x)

        if abs(w[-1] - w[-2]) < err:
            break
    return w[-1]
```

For reference, my error statement says a list index in the if clause is out of range. I assume this is because there's only one element in w since I don't know how to make the for loop. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you missed the intent of that exercise, if you can use `inv`, then you can also use `linalg.inv(A)` or better `linalg.solve(A,b)`. Note that you have sign errors and that the multiplication `*` is not the matrix multiplication between numpy arrays. (Your declaration of the arrays is incompatible with their later use.)

---

Your specific problem can be solved by adding an additional test

```
    if i>1 and abs(w[-1] - w[-2]) < err:
```

when the first condition fails the second is not evaluated.

---

You should contemplate if it is a waste of memory to construct the `w` list when all you ever need is the last two entries.

```
x_last, x = x, jacobi_step(A,b,x)
```

would also work to have these available.

The preparation can be reduced to

```
D=np.diag(A); A_reduced = A-np.diag(D);
```

then the Jacobi step is simply, using that the arithmetic operations are applied element-wise by default

```
x_last, x = x, (b-A_reduced.dot(x))/D
```

Comment: It would appear that the construction of the list is not needed since he only returns the last element.

Comment: @sokato : You need the last vector to compute the update. This can be done in different ways, but the extra vector can not be avoided.